# What happens to timestamp when passing to MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

```
call TimestampTest(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

Works:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TimestampTest`(theTimeStamp TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Log(`Timestamp`, `Text`)
    VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'test');
END
```

Does not work:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TimestampTest`(theTimeStamp TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Log(`Timestamp`, `Text`)
    VALUES(theTimeStamp, 'test');
END
```

When executing the INSERT statement I get:
'201401291550024.000000' is not a valid floating point value

So what happens to TIMESTAMP when passing through the stored procedure? Using a SQL Debugger I see that the **theTimeStamp** parameter has a valid value but when executing the INSERT I get that "is not a valid floating point value" error.

Answer (score 1):

The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function may not return a TIMESTAMP as might be expected. It is a synonym for NOW(). This is probably the cause of your issues.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: Thank your for your answer! Changing the procedure signature (using DATETIME type instead of TIMESTAMP type) did it.